# How can I display a new random number on each line with a JavaScript for loop?

Tags: javascript, for-loop

How can display a new random number with each new line element?

Currently, my HTML is displaying
The number is 4
The number is 4
The number is 4
The number is 4
The number is 4

I would like it to show a random number with each line.
The number is 4
The number is 1
The number is 9
The number is 3
The number is 11

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>    

</head>
<body>

    <div id="info">

    </div>


    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>

var divInfo = document.getElementById('info');
var quote = document.createElement('p');

var randNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 11) + 1;
var messNum = '';



for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

    messNum = "The number is " + randNum + "</br>";
    divInfo.appendChild(quote);
    quote.innerHTML += messNum;

}
```

Comment: Put the `var randNum = Math.floor(...` line inside the for loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assigning `randNum` once outside of your for loop.

Put `randNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 11) + 1;` as your first line inside the for loop, that way it changes with every iteration

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>    

</head>
<body>

    <div id="info">

    </div>


    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>

var divInfo = document.getElementById('info');
var quote = document.createElement('p');
var messNum = '';



for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    var randNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 11) + 1;
    messNum = "The number is " + randNum + "</br>";
    divInfo.appendChild(quote);
    quote.innerHTML += messNum;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to calculate the random number inside the `for` loop. So for each line it will get a different number like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    // calculate random here
    var randNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 11) + 1;
    messNum = "The number is " + randNum + "</br>";
    // ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a good start.  Just move your call to generate the random number inside your for-loop.  Try this:

```
<script>
    var divInfo = document.getElementById('info');
    var quote = document.createElement('p');
    var randNum;
    var messNum = '';

    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        randNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 11) + 1;
        messNum = "The number is " + randNum + "</br>";
        divInfo.appendChild(quote);
        quote.innerHTML += messNum;

    }
</script>
```

Here's a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/timdockins/0ma2byeh/) for it.